# ISP-to-ISP fast file transfer?

Tags: linux, networking, system-administration, data-transfer

Jeff Atwood talked about doing an ISP-to-ISP file transfer:

http://friendfeed.com/e/63fb9e72-6cd5-a8ac-88dc-02ce720033f9/wow-just-did-an-isp-to-isp-file-transfer-650mb-in/

What is this?  I tried Googling for it, but couldn't find anything.  We have a need to transfer large amounts of data between two data centers, and this sounds interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He just meant he was transferring data between 2 servers behind large internet connections (OC-1, etc).  Particularly between 2 datacenters which usually have internet connections in the measured in gbits.

I don't think he meant he was using some sort of special connection made.  Just using the large bandwidth ports provided with the server to transfer the data.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using a UDT/UDP based delivery solution to shift the data between a couple of locations..

http://udt.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

See also his recent blog post on [The Economics of Bandwidth](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000783.html).

It basically means using the main internet backbones, rather than going through the standard channels.

Answer (score 0):

FTP can be used to directly transfer data from one server to another, if the servers allow it.
It is called proxy FTP or third-party FTP.

Comment: If it is "directly", then, by definition, there is no proxy or third party.

Comment: That is what it's called, I didn't choose the names. I can't explain "Proxy FTP", but for each client to server connection the other server is the third party.

Answer (score 0):

[FXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol) might be what you are thinking.  The idea is your FTP client tells "FTP Server A" to go fetch a file from "FTP Server B".  Great idea in theory, but it is pretty insecure and thus you never find an ISP with FXP enabled.